# Max-heap implementation

Tags: c++, data-structures

Following code for max-heap implementation

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
#define  maxn 1000
int x[maxn];

int parent(int i){
    return int(i/2);

}
int left(int i){
    return 2*i;

}
int right(int i){
    return 2*i+1;

}
void  max_heap(int x[],int i,int size){
    int largest;
    int l=left(i);
    int r=right(i);

    if (l<=size &&  x[l]>x[i]){
        largest=l;
    }
    else
    {
        largest=i;
    }
    if (r<=size && x[r]>x[largest]){
    largest=r;
    }
    if (largest!=i)  { int s=x[i];x[i]=x[largest];x[largest]=s;}
    max_heap(x,largest,size);
}




int main(){

 x[1]=16;
 x[2]=4;
 x[3]=10;
 x[4]=14;
 x[5]=7;
 x[6]=9;
 x[7]=3;
 x[8]=2;
 x[9]=8;
 x[10]=1;
  int size=10;
  max_heap(x,2,size);
   for (int i=1;i<=10;i++)
       cout<<x[i]<<"  ";






    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it writes  such kind of warning:

```
1>c:\users\datuashvili\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\heap_property\heap_property\heap_property.cpp(36): warning C4717: 'max_heap' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow
```

Please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What should this code do? (other that failing during compilation)

Comment: Read this wiki article on recursion.[Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 18):

The message tells you exactly what's wrong. You haven't implemented any checks to stop the recursion. One smart compiler.

Answer (score 5):

`max_heap` function doesn't have base case, i.e., a return statement. You are just recursively calling the function but never saying when to break another successive call to the `max_heap`.

Also, in your example you are just calling the function with out satisfying any condition. Usually recursion is done or not done when a case is satisfied.

Comment: so what should it be  checking condition?

Comment: That depends on the algorithm you are using, which is `max_heap` in this case.

Comment: so max_heap algorthm's heap size is ten,so  terminating condition in general what is it?i have tried if (i==size) return ,but it does not work

Comment: It's not just about the return statement. You need to understand the mechanism of how recursion works. Another call to `max_heap(x,largest,size);` is just called with out satisfying any case. It inturns make another call and make another and so on ... Having a return statement just ends one such call but what about the other calls. They can in turn chain other calls. Please read the wiki link.

Comment: i know recursion,but i need here helping,i have used recursion so many times

Answer (score 0):

> please tell me what is wrong?

Another problem that I see is that the size of your array x is 10. But the indices that you are using to set values are 1-10.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
max_heap(x,largest,size);
```

inside last check, like this:

```
if (largest!=i)  
{ 
    int s=x[i];
    x[i]=x[largest];
    x[largest]=s;
    max_heap(x,largest,size);
}
```

and you're done!

There are many other problems with your code, but to answer your specific question, above change would do!